# Is vsprintf() guaranteed not to access va_list if format string makes no % references?

Tags: c, printf, variadic-functions

If the format string passed to `vsprintf()` (and variants thereof) contains no %-references, is it guaranteed that the va_list argument is not accessed?

Put another way, is:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main ( void ) {
    char    str[16];
    va_list ap;         /* never initialized */

    (void)vsnprintf(str, sizeof(str), "", ap);
    return 0;
}
```

a standard-conforming program?  or is there undefined behavior there?

The example above is obviously silly, but imagine a function which can be called by both a variadic function and a fixed-args function, grossly simplified into something like:

```
void somefuncVA ( const char * fmt, va_list ap ) {
    char    str[16];
    int     n;

    n = vsnprintf(str, sizeof(str), fmt, ap);
    /* potentially do something with str */
}

void vfoo ( const char * fmt, ... ) {
    va_list ap;

    va_start(fmt, ap);
    somefuncVA(fmt, ap);
}

void foo ( void ) {
    va_list ap;     /* no way to initialize this */

    somefuncVA("", ap);
}
```

Comment: There is no such a guarantee in the standard. http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.12p2 - *... argument list replaced by arg, **which shall have been initialized** by the va_start macro ...*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int vsprintf(char * restrict s, const char * restrict format, va_list arg);
```

> If the format string passed to `vsprintf()` ... contains no %-references, is it guaranteed that the `va_list` argument is not accessed.

No.

> The `vsprintf` function is equivalent to `sprintf`, with the variable argument list
>   replaced by `arg`, which **shall have been initialized** by the `va_start` macro .....
>   C11dr §7.21.6.13

Since the below code does not adhere to the spec, the result is *undefined behavior* (UB).  No guarantees.  [@Eugene Sh.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51383847/is-vsprintf-guaranteed-not-to-access-va-list-if-format-string-makes-no-refer#comment89739730_51383847)

```
va_list ap;
//                                    vv-- ap not initialized
(void)vsnprintf(str, sizeof(str), "", ap);
```

---

> Is `vsprintf()` guaranteed not to access `va_list` if format string makes no % references?

With a properly passed `va_list arg`, `vsprintf()` acts like `sprintf()`.  Code like the following is OK.  It is permissible to pass extra arguments.  Via  `vsprintf()`, they (the extra arguments) are not accessed, yet `va_list arg` may be accessed.

```
sprintf(buf, "format without percent", 1.2345, 456)`
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have varargs passed to your function - your function isn't defined with `...` as the last parameter - there's simply never any need for any use of `va_list` or `va_start()` in that function.  If you want to pass an empty set of variable arguments, simply call the varargs function directly without any variable arguments - e.g., `printf("\n");`.

For example, instead of

```
void foo ( void ) {
    va_list ap;     /* no way to initialize this */

    somefuncVA("", ap);
}
```

you can just write

```
void foo ( void ) {
    vfoo("");
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  That works in this over simplified example, but not for me, alas (because of other arguments, etc).